# changing Bing Maps attribution

Tags: bing-maps, openlayers

I have been doing some research and found out that i can change the attributions of TileWMS, OSM but i have found little about BingMaps. Is it possible to change the attributions of BingMaps? and how do you go about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bing's terms of use require you to use the extent based attributions obtained through Bing's APIs. Because changing the attribution would be a violation of these terms, it is not supported in OpenLayers 3.

Comment: how can i have a custom attribution appended to ovewrite the bing maps, does that make sense?

Comment: Just add your customised attribution like in localized-openstreetmap.js see http://openlayers.org/en/vector-api/examples/localized-openstreetmap.html?q=attribution